# Setting a Func<T,bool> property using generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm trying to create a new object and set a property for a class that uses generics. I know I can create an object like this:

```
    var type = typeof(User<>).MakeGenericType(this.myObject.GetType());
    var context = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    
    
    public class User<T> 
        where T : class
    {
        public Func<T, bool> Condition { get; set; }
        public string ConditionText { get; set; }
    }
```

But how do I set a value for the Condition property using a similar way?

If I knew the type then I would do it like this:

```
User<Person> user = new User<Person>()
{
     Condition = (this.myExpression as Expression<Func<Person, bool>>).Compile(),
     ConditionText = "My text",
};
```

`this.myExpression` is type `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`

Comment: `type.GetProperty("Condition").SetValue(context, something);`?

Comment: Where are you getting a value to store into the `Condition` property from?

Comment: Did you know what type is <T>

Comment: I've updated my code above.

Comment: What do you want to set it to?

Comment: From your example, it seems that `something` in my suggestion is simply `this.myExpression.Compile();`. Some more clarification may be needed re what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What type is `this.myExpression`?

Comment: I've updated my code again it is type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression'

Comment: I think we need to know what the context is in which you want to use this. I think the solution will probably lie in wrapping this functionality in another generic type that is responsible for creating your User instance, at a point where T is known. Without context it's hard to tell though

Comment: You might be able to `((LambdaExpression)myExpression).Compile()`, to get a Delegate, and then set that using reflection